# Speed up Classify using GPU

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I am interested in classify binary data using a Random Forest method. My data is numeric tensor and label of each class represented by 1.0 or 0.0.
The size of the training data is ~16 million examples, and the size of the test data is around 500 million examples.

```
rfST = Classify[traningData, 
  Method -> {"RandomForest", "TreeNumber" -> 500}, 
  TrainingProgressReporting -> "Print", TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}]

predictionRes = 
  Transpose[
    Values[rfST[testData, "Probabilities", TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}]]][[
   2]];
```

To speed up the training and test, I am using `TargetDevice -> "GPU."`  When I am run the prediction I  "feel" that a GPU doesn't take part in computation,  however, the CPU is a computation engine. Please see the attached figures. 
[image]
[image]

Any suggestion on what to check to speed up the calculation
Note: I am using Win 10, and WL 11.3 and  the GPU is GTX 1080 (I update the  driver)

Comment: try to install [CUDA drivers](http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html) manually

Comment: I did it, but I don't see improvement.

Comment: `TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 2}` ?

Comment: similar performance, also I try  'TargetDevice -> {"GPU",{1,2}}'

Comment: What about `NetTrain` instead of `Classify` ?

Comment: The goal is to research the random forest performance, so I use Classify

Comment: What is the version of the GPU driver that Wolfram sees?  Try ``Needs["CUDALink`"]`` and then `CUDADriverVersion[]`.

Comment: @Edmund the GPU driver  version is "399.24"

Comment: The latest driver for the  GTX 1080 on Win 10 (64 bit) is "417.35". I suggest updating as that is the first thing Wolfram Support will advise you to do.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko I wasn't suggest you to switch to another goal, but I'd check if NetTrain makes use of the GPU

Comment: @Fortsaint aaa, I don't understand you correctly. the NetTrain  does not make use of the GPU too

Comment: @Edmund I am updating the driver, but unfortunately, the performance remain similar

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko You cannot use GPU because `RandomForest` method uses Intel DAAL library under the hood. To speed up training, use option `PerformanceGoal -> "DirectTraining"`.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Thank you for this approach speed up the training time. Also, I look for some workaround which may speed up the test any suggestion how to speed up this?

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko `Parallelize[Map[c, Partition[test, 1000]]]` where `c=ClassifierFunction[...]` and 1000 is the batch size. This may be a little faster (up to 20%), but depends heavily on the batch size (may be much slower!).